# working with geom_pointrange and geom_errorbar when you have several groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I have the mock data below:

```
df <- structure(list(country = c("Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", 
                           "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Austria", "Austria", 
                           "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", 
                           "Austria", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
                           "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany"), date = c(1000, 1200, 
                                                                                 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1750, 1800, 1000, 1200, 1300, 1400, 
                                                                                 1500, 1600, 1700, 1750, 1800, 1000, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 
                                                                                 1700, 1750, 1800), X = c(1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                          1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), fit.0.025quant = c(0.828491623257632, 
                                                                                                                                                                           2.44382034612151, 2.62478810453802, 2.6337062129497, 2.53478842319723, 
                                                                                                                                                                           1.65013735592875, 0.752635464354321, 0.662634760040262, 0.63361902939496, 
                                                                                                                                                                           0.631636426187967, 0.64989986512676, 0.650190687845941, 0.65019680371168, 
                                                                                                                                                                           0.650196959453982, 0.650196803680857, 0.650190687868955, 0.64989986513554, 
                                                                                                                                                                           0.631636426203261, 0.631636426187967, 0.64989986512676, 0.650190687845941, 
                                                                                                                                                                           0.65019680371168, 0.650196959453982, 0.650196803680857, 0.650190687868955, 
                                                                                                                                                                           0.64989986513554, 0.631636426203261), fit.mean = c(1.19020910017421, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              2.83008460257499, 2.98078335406727, 2.98765164881975, 2.90462557038579, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              1.99996297933676, 1.09510738941705, 1.01024668622426, 1.00139011636246, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              1.00000323935823, 1.0000015167136, 1.00000147625773, 1.00000147475972, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              1.00000147470401, 1.00000147476084, 1.00000147625788, 1.00000151671303, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              1.00000323935854, 1.00000323935823, 1.0000015167136, 1.00000147625773, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              1.00000147475972, 1.00000147470401, 1.00000147476084, 1.00000147625788, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              1.00000151671303, 1.00000323935854), fit.0.975quant = c(1.61097812296572, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      3.17395283857941, 3.326527054585, 3.33442175855909, 3.24708594348506, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      2.3497438234016, 1.46469784405916, 1.36349195359207, 1.37038568954042, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      1.36836869801455, 1.35010013487928, 1.34980931215949, 1.34980319628983, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      1.34980304054122, 1.34980319632293, 1.34980931213498, 1.35010013486874, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      1.36836869799899, 1.36836869801455, 1.35010013487928, 1.34980931215949, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      1.34980319628983, 1.34980304054122, 1.34980319632293, 1.34980931213498, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      1.35010013486874, 1.36836869799899)), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -27L))
```

I have two related questions.

I can plot df as:

```
ggplot(df, 
       aes(x = X, y = fit.mean)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = fit.0.025quant, ymax = fit.0.975quant),
                  color = "red") + 
  xlab("Observed values") + 
  ylab("Fitted values") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-1,7)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,7,1))
```

It produces:

[image]

Question 1: For "1" and "3" it shows several means (big dots). I want each to show only one mean, the one in the middle. It is the mean of all "fit.mean" for "1".

Similar problem with "errorbars":

```
ggplot(df, 
       aes(x = X, y = fit.mean)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = fit.0.025quant, ymax = fit.0.975quant), 
                color = "red") + 
  xlab("Observed values") + 
  ylab("Fitted values") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-1,7)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,7,1))
```

It produces:

[image]

Question 2: For "1" and "3", I want each to show only upper and lower bars (red horizontal lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the simplest way is to compute the mean of all `fit.mean` and so on for `X`s as below

```r
df2=df%>%
  group_by(X)%>%
  mutate(across(fit.0.025quant:fit.0.975quant, ~ mean(.x)))
```

**second way** :
To plot the min q25 and max for q95 you only have to change the `mutate` arguments. Here i conserved the same names so i do not have to change the plot arguments

buy you can do something like `mutate(mean_all=mean(fit.mean))` here you conserve the fit.mean and produce a new variable mean_all that you will call in your ggplot2 aesthetic arguments

```
df2=df%>%
  group_by(X)%>%
  mutate(mean = mean(fit.mean),
         fit.0.025quant=min(fit.0.025quant),
         fit.0.975quant=max(fit.0.975quant))
```

with df2  your plots are fine

```
ggplot(df2, 
       aes(x = X, y = fit.mean)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = fit.0.025quant, ymax = fit.0.975quant),
                  color = "red") + 
  xlab("Observed values") + 
  ylab("Fitted values") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-1,7)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,7,1))
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df2, 
       aes(x = X, y = fit.mean)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = fit.0.025quant, ymax = fit.0.975quant), 
                color = "red") + 
  xlab("Observed values") + 
  ylab("Fitted values") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-1,7)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,7,1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: this is a clever way, but its disadvantage is that part of information gets lost. For example, if you look at errorbars in my picture, then the upper bar for "1" gets stretched above 1.5, and this is the upper bar that I want to keep. While in your example, upper bar for "1" is below 1.5.  Averaging "fit.mean" is okay, but is it possible to select the highest value for each "fit.0.975quant", and then the least value for "fit.0.025quant"?

Comment: yes, i edited my answer accordingly